# R count function calls

Tags: r, callstack

This should be easy, but can't find any straight-forward answers on google or SO.

Imagine in R I run a function `FOuter()`, and within its body, it does some loop and calls another function `FInner()`. Is there a simple way of counting/recording the number of times `FInner` gets called?  I'm trying to estimate how much time I can save if I optimize `FInner`.

Comment: I looked a bit at Rprof.  That seems to do some kind of "sampling" and then provides some sort of time measurement spend on a certain function.  What I'm looking for is a bit more fundamental.  When I call FOuter, I want to know exactly how many times FInner got called.

Comment: The simplest solution I can think of would be to increment a counter before every call to `FInner`, and just return the counter with the output with `return(list(normal.output,counter))`.

Answer (score 9):

You're looking for `trace`.

```
f1 <- function() 1
f2 <- function() {
    for(i in 1:10) f1()
}

.count <- 0
trace(f1, tracer=function() .count <<- .count +1)
f2()
.count
# 10
untrace(f1)
```