# trace that includes variable modification within testthat

Tags: r, testthat

I have two functions, one of which calls the other in a semi-recursive fashion depending on arguments.

```
f1 <- function(use_f2 = FALSE){
  if (use_f2) {
    f2()
  }
}

f2 <- function(){
  f1(use_f2 = FALSE)
}
```

I want to keep track of how many times each function is called depending on the arguments, and then have that as part of a unit test using `testthat`.

I can keep track of how many calls are made using a custom environment and `trace` (see [here](https://gist.github.com/rmflight/20f10db5c27b3623c321) for what I did previously), as shown in a [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21687514/r-count-function-calls)

```
function_counts <- new.env()
function_counts$f1 <- function_counts$f2 <- 0

trace(f1, tracer = quote(function_counts$f1 <- function_counts$f1 + 1), print = FALSE)
trace(f2, tracer = quote(function_counts$f2 <- function_counts$f2 + 1), print = FALSE)

f1()
function_counts$f1
function_counts$f2
```

This works nicely, until I add in the complication of `testthat` environments.

If I put

```
count_env <- new.env()

count_env$f1 <- 0

trace(f1, tracer = quote(count_env$f1 <<- count_env$f1 + 1), print = FALSE)
```

either outside or inside the `test_that` block, **and then run `devtools::test()`** or *ctrl-shift-t* in *rstudio*, which tests in special environments, I will get `count_env not found`. I realize this is all interplay between environments of `trace` and `testthat`, but I'm not able to decipher it.

I have also tried making the `count_env` object an unexported object of the package itself, but that didn't seem to work either.

[This](https://github.com/rmflight/tt_trace_mre) repo has a minimal package with these two functions and a `testthat` tests directory to play with this.

Any help on where to go from here would be great.

Comment: This question is essentially a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21687514/r-count-function-calls

Comment: Also, first example in the link you provide seems to work

Comment: @RomanTsegelskyi really? by calling `devtools::test()` on the package, or Ctrl-shift-t in rstudio? because that always failed for me

Comment: no, just by running the code. I guess you should add that the test has to be called with `devtools::test()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the answer is to use **local** variables, and a **local** function that is defined within the call to `trace`.

```
.f1 <- .f2 <- 0

trace(f1, tracer = function() {.f1 <<- .f1 + 1}, print = FALSE)
trace(f2, tracer = function() {.f2 <<- .f2 + 1}, print = FALSE)

test_that("f1 FALSE", {
  f1()
  expect_equal(1, .f1)
  expect_equal(0, .f2)
})
```

Thanks to Steph Locke for pointing to the example where an anonymous function was used, and for the initial pull request.